# How to check whether the elements of an ArrayList are all contained in another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, subset, containment

How can I easily check to see whether all the elements in one ArrayList are all elements of another ArrayList?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [Collection.containsAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)):

```
boolean isSubset = listA.containsAll(listB);
```

Comment: is there anything available so that a new array is generated containing all data that's shared in listA and listB? Object[] subset = listA.shared(listB)

Comment: Set common = new HashSet(listA); common.retainAll(listB); // now "common" contains only the common elements

Comment: Is there a way to check for the order of the elements as well? I tried this and it was true even though I'd changed the order of the elements. Is there a way to do what I'd like to do?

Comment: How to check if ATLEAST ONE  of the elements of a String ArrayList are  contained in another String ArrayList??

Comment: As this is case sensitive, how to validate for case insensitive lists?

Answer (score 2):

There is a containsAll method in all collections.