# How to check if array a is part of array b in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808394/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

I have array `a = { 1,4,3,5,1,2,3,6 }` and array `b= { 1,2,3 }`.

How can I check if array `b` elements appear anywhere in array `a`? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's trivial in `O(n^2)`. It is relatively easy in `O(n log n)` as well. What have you tried?

Comment: Just FYI, answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: should the elements be placed together or each element of b can be found anywhere within a?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify your arrays, in particular to sort them? Are thes `int[]` arrays of primitive type, or `Integer[]` arrays containing objects? The latter would work well with `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(…)).containsAll(…)`.

Comment: @assylias, what works for `ArrayList` won't work for primitive arrays of primitive element type.

Comment: @ Abhishek Bhatia, the elements of b should be placed together and found anywhere in a. Thanks.

Comment: @user1172575 I'm not sure you understood the question of @AbhishekBhatia In your example the elements of `b` are not *together* in `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang):

```
for (Object element:b) {
    if (ArrayUtils.contains(a,element) == false) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is obviously to use the built-in functions.  However, Java only has built-in functions to do this for `Collection` types. If the arrays are not of primitive types, you can do this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(a).containsAll(Arrays.asList(b))) {
   //...
}
```

If it's a primitive array (`int[]`, etc) this is still the easiest approach, you just need to convert the array into a list manually or using a third-party library.  [Guava has functions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) for this:

```
if ( Ints.asList(a).containsAll(Ints.asList(b)) ) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I converted the arrays to lists but still can't recognize the Ints.asList and this is the code.  //convert our arrays to lists
  List alist = (List) Arrays.asList(a);
  List blist = (List) Arrays.asList(b);
  
  if (Ints.asList(blist).containsAll(Ints.asList(a))) {
   System.out.print("yes");
  }else
  System.out.print("no");

Comment: @user1172575 In a comment you said the elements of `b` should be together but this will return true even if they are not.

Comment: @madth3, if they're not fount in b, it should return false, why it would return true even if they're not?

Comment: @user1172575: As I said in my answer, `Ints.asList` is a function of Guava, a very popular third-party library.